# Detect only swipe events over an overlay div

Tags: css, swipe, hammer.js, pointer-events

I am trying to detect left,right swipe events on the screen using hammer.js.
Currently its detecting swipe action over entire screen area since i am passing the main content div class.I've created an overlay div covering half of the screen area and its class is passed when hammer is initialized.So now the swipe is working fine over that area ,but all other pointer events to content below the overlay is blocked. 
Is it possible to pass all other pointer events to underlying divs except the swipe events ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your problem description correctly and re-phrasing it as follows: You want to use an additional recognizer along with your existing swipe(left, right) events.

- You can add a new event on the same manager instance that you had already created [[1]](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#hammer.manager)
- Even if you've separated out both the events and still want to execute them simultaneously then use `recognizeWith` [[2]](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognize-with/)